# How to hatch a Rectangle in Corel Draw X6?

Tags: coreldraw

I have made some drawings in Corel Draw X6 now i need to `hatch a rectangle`. How can i do that ? I googled but didn't find any useful answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have sorted out this problem by watching corel draw tutorials.

Select the rectangle (which you have to hatch) > Go to **fill tool** (from left toolbar) > Select **Pattern Fill** > Select **Two Color** > Click on arrow > you will see many hatching options > Select thatone you want.

In my case I wanted **Inclined hatch** so I selected **Vertical line** and place an angle of 45 degree.